# How to use multiple async or buffered IO-Streams?

Tags: c#, iostream

I am currently working on a program that writes a lot of data (~100mb) to .txt-files. I googled a bit on how to optimize the different IO-Streams, but didn't really understand the following:

1. How to open multiple streams at once
2. If the stream is buffered by default or if i have to us BufferedStream
3. What the difference between an async and a buffered stream is

Here is the current state of my output:

```
for (int Row = 0; Row < RowCount; Row++)
{                   
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
        new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Calculations\data1.txt", true))
            {
                file.WriteLine(Time + "\t" + Row + "\t" + Value1[Row]);
            }
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
        new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Calculations\data2.txt", true))
            {
                file.WriteLine(Time + "\t" + tRow + "\t" + Value2[Row]);
            }
}
```

What i think this does:

- Opens stream to data1.txt
- Writes to data1.txt
- Closes und flushes stream
- Opens stream to data2.txt
- Writes to data2.txt
- Closes and flushes stream

If I'm correct with that, that would be a LOT of opening, closing and flushing for 100mb of data. I'd love to just open multiple streams at the start, write all the data while it's being calculated and then close and flush the streams.

Comment: The OS already makes writing to files async, a basic job of the file system cache.  Writes occur to memory, the cache manager lazily writes it to disk.  100MB is not enough to help it, makes it worse actually due to the required buffering.

Comment: Why not move your using statements before the for loop? `using(StreamWriter file1=new StreamWriter(...), file2 = new StreamWriter(...)) { for(...) { file1.WriteLine(...); file2.WriteLine(...); }}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot in your question

Some random points in no particular order

1. All streams have an internal buffer in .net
2. No you don't have to buffer them, however you can adjust the size of the internal buffer for performance reasons (this depends on a lot of factors)
3. Asynchronous IO is a very complex topic, Start reading here [Asynchronous File I/O](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/asynchronous-file-i-o)

Further more.

Since buffering is taken careof by the stream, you don't need to worry about it, it will flush it when it needs to (according to the default or how you set the buffer). You don't need to close the file for it to flush. Once again, let the stream take care of it, or if you like you can flush it your self using 'Flush'

100mb is not a lot for a modern SSD drive, its can be done in milliseconds. And once again there is no need to open and close it if you don't need to. However on saying that, there is overhead opening and closing a file but its minimal, so its sometimes beneficial/aesy to wrap the access in a `using` statement and read and write in on a peace-meal basis

And lastly, yes you can open multiple streams, but they are not thread safe. Meaning, since they only have 1 internal buffer you will have to either use a lock, or open and close the file to ensure its integrity. That's not saying multiple threads cant write to a file, its just saying its not as trivial as it aught to be.

If you want to keep the files open to read and write synchronously, just don't forget to close/dispose them when you have finished

Good luck

Comment: Is thread safety an issue if i write to different files with different streams, each in it's own thread? Right now I open and close my stream ~200.000 times and i would like to have one stream for each file which i can keep open.

Comment: @LorenzMichalski sorry if it wasn't clear, no thread safety is only an issue if you have threads writing and reading from the one stream, you can have several streams open with no problems, just as long as you write and read from them synchronously

Answer (score 1):

After some more research I found a solution for my first question. You can open multiple IO-Streams like this:

```
StreamWriter file1 = File.CreateText(@"C:\Outputtests\OutputTest1.txt");
StreamWriter file2 = File.CreateText(@"C:\Outputtests\OutputTest2.txt");
```

Like this you need to flush and close the streams yourself.

I compared the running times, it saves about a factor 10000 for my hdd:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch sw1 = new Stopwatch();
    Stopwatch sw2 = new Stopwatch();
    Stopwatch sw3 = new Stopwatch();

    sw1.Start();                            //first version: opens and closes file each time -> takes around 1 minute total
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file1 =
            new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Outputtests\OutputTest1.txt", true))
        {
            file1.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
    sw1.Stop();

    sw2.Start();                            //second version: flushes each time -> takes around 50ms
    StreamWriter file2 = File.CreateText(@"C:\Outputtests\OutputTest2.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        file2.WriteLine(i);
        file2.Flush();
    }
    file2.Close();
    sw2.Stop();

    sw3.Start();                            //third version: flushes at the end -> takes around 10ms
    StreamWriter file3 = File.CreateText(@"C:\Outputtests\OutputTest3.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        file3.WriteLine(i);
    }
    file3.Flush();
    file3.Close();
    sw3.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Output 1:\t" + sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "Output 2:\t" + sw2.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "Output 3:\t" + sw3.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Not sure though how much you should store in the IO-Stream until you have to flush it.

Comment: It flushes at about 4k, which is extremely inefficient for ssd's. though it does depend on what you are doing